# What Is Active db in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**What Is Active db in CodeIgniter**

I have been searching but I am not getting answer in this question?

Please answer me.

Comment: Hit [the manual](https://codeigniter.com/docs) not SO

Comment: In that manual i am not getting active db

Comment: Its called active record so try here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html Is google banned in your country

Comment: As what RiggsFolly said but here is the active record for CI3 but changed name http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's Active Record not Active DB. Active Record is a One kind of design pattern used for retrieve, insert, and update your database with minimal scripting. You will find more about this in the bellow link

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html And this for CI3